# django ImpropertlyConfigured. The included urlsconf does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django

I am using django 2.2.2 . I am trying to include `path('api/', include('music.urls')),`into my root url but I get an exception thrown from resolvers.py  file.

Here is my music/urls.py

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'music'


urlpatterns = [
path('songs/', ListSongsView.as_view(), name = 'songs-all'),

]
```

here is my root url file
**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include


urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/', include('music.urls')),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Songs
from serializers import SongSerializer

# Create your views here.


class ListSongsView(generics.ListApiView):
    queryset            = Songs.objects.all()
    serializer_class    = SongsSerializer
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Songs(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
    artist      = models.CharField(max_length=50, null= False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.title, self.artist)
```

and my stacktrace

```
File "/home/brianonchari/Documents/django/drf/myapi/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'rest.urls' does not 
appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is 
probably caused by a circular import.
```

Comment: The error tells about `'rest.urls'` do you have it in your code?

Comment: yes. I think it should be the root url

Comment: can you show where you have the 'rest.urls' code written?

Comment: Eliminate the last comma from your urlspatterns list. Sometime it caused the circular import error. `urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/', include('music.urls')) #comma deleted from here

]`

Comment: where is `rest.urls` in your project??

Comment: `from django.contrib import admin
     from django.urls import path,include
     urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('music.urls')),

 ]`   This is my rest.urls @Lag11

Comment: @IqbalHussain I have tried to that ,  It's not working for my case

Comment: @BrianO, Can you provide your models in your question. Songs model.py file

Comment: @IqbalHussain I have added it to the question

Comment: @Brian, provide SongsSerializer class in your answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**music/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ListSongsView
app_name = 'music'


urlpatterns = [
    path('songs/', ListSongsView.as_view(), name='songs-all'),

]
```

root **urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('music.urls')),

]
```

**music/views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Songs
from .serializers import SongSerializer

# Create your views here.


class ListSongsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Songs.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongSerializer
```

**music/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Songs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.title, self.artist)
```

music/serializers.py:

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from .models import Songs


   class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

       class Meta:
           model = Songs
           fields = ('title', 'artist')
```

run your migration for **Songs** model:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: `from rest_framework import serializers
     from .models import Songs
     class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         class Meta:
             model   = Songs
      fields  = ('title', 'artist') ` Here is my serializer. Still doen't work. Its driving me crazy

Comment: @BrianO, Please have a look on the updated answer. i have checked that code and its running at my end.

Comment: @Brian, Thanks Brian for your patience :)